# Usage of "self-absorbed" to describe metaphors

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I recently posted a few metaphors I came up with and someone on a stack exchange website said it was overly descriptive and "self-absorbed," and *another* person said it was "self-indulgent."

My question is how can metaphors be *self*-absorbed or *self*-indulgent? Wouldn't the *self* refer to the metaphors? They were saying the metaphors themselves were overly descriptive and etc.

I can see how people can use words the way they want to, but how do the usage of those words in that context even make sense?

If I said I wrote self-indulgent metaphors, that would make sense, but saying the metaphors themselves were self-indulgent makes me perplexed? Is that correct usage?

Also, just curious, but what would the difference be between:

I wrote self-indulgent metaphors.

The metaphors I wrote were self-indulgent.

I self-indulgently wrote metaphors.

Comment: We can't really tell you what other people mean when they use adjectives. If the dictionary doesn't cover it for you, you should ask the originators of the expressions.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you're referring to specific metaphors, you should add them to the question. Otherwise, it seems you are asking multiple things, each of which would have a subjective answer.

Comment: I’m asking if using self-absorbed to refer to metaphors is correct usage. Well, the writing stack exchange doesn’t let me give examples. Am I allowed to post examples of my writing on this stack exchange?

Comment: I don't see how a "metaphor" can be something you come up with and post in and of itself. A metaphor is a tool, not an end result.

Comment: Do you suggest me adding “description of” in front of every usage of the word metaphor? Sometimes words are omitted or implied e.g. I wrote down what happened.

Comment: You may include a link to the page where the conversation took place.  Some context would be helpful!  However, it seems unlikely the question would remain open even if we can see the context.  But we might be able to help you understand better what was written.  Please ping me when you provide the link.  That is, include @aparente001 in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Metonymy is common in English, with context critical to understanding.

Just as the previous sentence used *English* to refer to the users of the language, your correspondents used *metaphor* to reference the person introducing the metaphor - namely, you.

Metaphors are not beings, capable of contemplation. So your correspondents were really saying that *you* were self-absorbed or self-indulgent by (you) introducing the metaphor.